# Настройка .htaccess и mod_rewrite: убирать расширение .php у файлов

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Многое прочитал на стаке, но так ничего и не заработало в моём случае. Раньше делал подобное на nginx, и все было просто и понятно. Столкнулся с htaccess на хостинге, нужна помощь.

На данный момент имею это:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Этот код по идее убирает расширение .php на конце, конечно возможно неправильно.

Хотелось бы следующие примеры ЧПУ:

1. https://example.com/menu/30/ вместо https://example.com/menu?id=30
2. https://example.com/custom/booking/6000/ вместо https://example.com/custom/booking?amount=6000

И если можно, то хотелось бы, чтобы на всех ссылках на конце был закрывающий `/`. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для двух ваших примеров будет работать:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(.+)\?(.+)=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3/? [L,R=301]
```